# c# Web Browser simulate button press

Tags: c#, browser, button, simulate

I'm using the WebBrowser control and want to bypass a button press on a web page. I'm not very familiar with HTML  and web pages, but I'm wondering if anyone has a solution.

The button I'm talking about is on this web page:
http://www.movshare.net/video/ut55cfdvg5wgj/?

The button is appearing at random so it might not be there always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Thinking about this, you can do most of this from the C#.  Updated.

Get a reference to the button and invoke it's `click()` JavaScript method:

```
HtmlElement btn = myBrowserControl.Document.GetElementById("myButton");
/*
Alternatively, take a look at these other methods for retrieving an HtmlElement:
HtmlDocument.GetElementFromPoint(Point point)
HtmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName(string tagName)
HtmlDocument.All.GetElementsByName(string name)
*/
btn.InvokeMember("click");
```

<strike>This will only work in all browsers if ...</strike>
Since this is a WebBrowser control, you don't need to worry about cross browser issues.

Comment: Perfect! I think I got ot to work, didn't get the button to appear :D so I tested it on another site.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the user to skip the button press everytime. Then this means, you don't need the button at all on the page. Please put more information